# Play a sound when the progressbar reaches the end, not working!

Tags: android, audio

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer
    {

```
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep1);

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {
        mp.start();
        //Start.this.finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
        total++;
        progre.setProgress(total);
    }   
}
```

I want topaly a sound when the progress bar reaches the end (after 30sec) but it's not playing.

Can anybody help me??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following line:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityName.this, R.raw.beep1);
```

the 'this' in your code is referring to the MyCount class buut you want to use the Activity.

Comment: Solved, i just had to put in the class:
MediaPlayer mp;
and then in Oncreate:
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep1);

=D Thank you for the answers anyway =D

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm. It should work because you are playing from a raw resource...maybe the mediaplayer is already being used by something else.  Try putting mp.reset() then mp.prepare() before mp.start().

Let me know if that works...

Also JDx answer above may do the trick.

Comment: Solved, i just had to put in the class:
MediaPlayer mp;
and then in Oncreate:
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep1);

=D Thank you for the answers anyway =D